# My MVP license is expire, how can I request for new one?

Tags: mvp, license

I have been awarded Sitecore MVP this year and my last year's Sitecore MVP license is expired. What is the process to request for new Sitecore license?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like a license, please email [mvp-program@sitecore.com](https://mailto:mvp-program@sitecore.com) and the team will get back to you as soon as possible.

More information on what can you do with your Sitecore MVP Licence: [What can I do with my Sitecore MVP license?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/what-can-i-do-with-my-sitecore-mvp-license)